# PayPal in-context view redirecting not closing window

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the PayPal in-context approach and upon launching PayPal in an in-context manner, I am able to:

- Log in
- Pay for my items

But after that, PayPal redirects me to the URL I provide however it does this within the in-context view? Is there a setting I am missing to make it close the mini window it opens after user pays? The documentation doesn't specify/mention anything on how to do this. I was expecting it to close the in-context window when a user clicks "pay now" and return back control to the page hosting it.

Apologies if the detail in the question seems light, if any further info is required then please comment and I shall try my best to update.

Should mention I am using the sandbox environment.

Answer (score 1):

When using the PayPal In-Context checkout you should have a fully functional Express Checkout flow to begin with. There are some variables that would cause the In-Context checkout to display as the standard Express Checkout. This would cause the issue you are speaking about. I have a functional In-Context checkout here:
http://marshalcurrier.com/paypal/ExpressCheckout/SetDoInContext.php

I tried to implement In-Context Checkout with the WooCommerce plugin on Wordpress. This didnt work out so well, you can see what the checkout looks like here:
http://marshalcurrier.com/?product=test

For the most part the opening and closing should be handled through PayPal. That is why you call PayPal's Script:

For the most part everything was built to be plug and play. You drop in this near the end of your page:

```
<form id="myContainer" method="post" action="/checkout"></form>

<script>
  window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () { 
    paypal.checkout.setup('9XKWYX3UHBPB2', {
        environment: 'sandbox',
        container: 'myContainer'
      }); 
  };
</script>
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

Then add the div id to your form:

```
<form method='post' id="myContainer"><input type="text" name="CHARGE" value="1"/><input type="submit"/><form>
```

I have functioning sample code but need to get 10 reputation before I can post it.

Comment: I have done all the apart from setting the container like you have done there. I adjusted my code to do that but still insists on performing the redirect in the in-context window. The only way I have got round this is to on the successUrl redirect to a page where onload() it simply does a window.close().

Comment: This is my full code. It is a 1 page example. The credentials are free for you to test if you'd like.

http://marshalcurrier.com/paypal/ExpressCheckout/SetDoInContext.txt

Here is the functioning test In Context:
http://marshalcurrier.com/paypal/ExpressCheckout/SetDoInContext.php

If you could provide sample code I would be willing to take a look and try to find a solution for you.

Comment: Not sure whether it matters but would the angularjs cause any conflicts whilst hosting the page in context. I don't think it would but I simplify the app of mine and post the code

Comment: I went and asked another agent to test their code and they are having the same issue. I then looked into it. There is a bug currently and we are rolling back the changes that caused the issue. I will post an update as soon as I hear more about it.

Comment: That's great thanks for the info. I was losing my marbles reading the documentation over and over but glad you guys are onto it. Cheers.

Comment: I just tested. It looks like things are back up and running. From what I hear there might be a bit of a delay with the roll back being applied to all servers, but it should be up and running now. Let me know how this works out for you.